# How to exclude any react native library for specific build

Tags: react-native

- I have 3 environments development, testing, production in my React Native app

  - Android is managed by flavours + buildTypes
  - iOS is managed by different schema + configurations
- I have a library that serves only testing purposes (sending info about testing sessions like device ids, user names, video recording etc.)
- I don't use this in production at all, it should be only an internal thing
- I manage that now by `if-else` + `.env`, but...

I don't want that (potentially risky if misconfigured) library to be in the production build at all. I want to completely exclude it.

How do you manage that for Android and iOS builds? Any tips and tricks are welcome.

I tried to add `react-native.config.js` as described in documentation [react-native-community dependencies](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/dependencies.md), but then the error `Library not found was raised`.

```
module.exports = {
  'my-library-name': {
    platforms: {
      ios: {
        configurations: ['testing'],
      },
      android: {
        buildTypes: ['testingRelease'],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: is it helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62037022/react-native-0-60-exclude-library-from-autolink?

Comment: hmhm...not sure how to apply this to only some specific build type...maybe here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/dependencies.md